# Python: Method of checking for a string in a list of strings but only in a specific place within the list. Like checking if "a" is in the first slot

Tags: python, string, list, character

Most solutions to checking for a value in a list are just general checks, like if "a" is anywhere in the list return true. If the list is

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to see if "a" is in the first slot. I'm pretty new to python, so I'm not sure how complicated the solution is going to be.

Comment: `my_list[0] == 'a' `?

Answer (score 0):

To see if `'a'` is in the the first slot, you simply write:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if list[0] == 'a':
    print('yes')
```

If you wanted to find the index number, the code is:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in list:
    if i == 'a':
        print('index: %s' % list.index(i))
```

This will tell you the index number, however if you wanted the slot number, you change `list.index(i)` to `int(list.index(i) + 1)` and `%s` to `%d`.